# Migrating Wordpress blog to New Webhosts, something is adding a # and gibberish

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I just migrated a WordPress blog from one host provider to another.

Did a clean install on the new server, and everything seems to be working fine except all the permalinks for some reason add a string on the end like this:

http://keefermadness.com/2011/09/behind-the-scenes-of-my-nasa-grail-experience-day-one-am#.Tpq5DpzpP-g

That #.Tpq5DpzpP-g shouldn't be there. Any idea where this is coming from and how to eliminate it?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: First I thought, it could be a session id for the server. But the part after the # is not send to the server. just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just figured it out. In the migration, the settings were slightly different in the "Add This" plugin. I had selected "Track address bar shares" which added the # and the characters for tracking purposes. That is now removed.